# Why does my React app is not shown in Github host?

Tags: reactjs, github

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.0"
  }
```

used this on package.json

```json
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
```

this in scripts also in package.json
and also filled up homepage script but it doesn't show anything
this is whats on screen, here is image >>[hosting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zthES.png)<<
and have no idea whats going on i went step by step on hosting tutorial, but i already done project and then tried to host and in tutorial they made on creating new project and hosting it maybe i did something wrong because of that?

Comment: hey there, did you add the homepage property in your package.json?

Comment: Github pages uses different Branch for its pages. Verify in Settings under pages tab what is the branch name.